# spring jpa custom repository not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Trying to create a custom repository implementation with spring and getting the following 
error:

```
caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
  qualifying bean of type [com.mynamespace.domain.repository.GenericRepositoryImpl] 
  found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
  candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here is my code (download it from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11115278/src-spring-problem/SpringSimple.zip.renameit):

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
        SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericRepository<T, ID> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private Class<T> domainClass;

    public GenericRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {

        super(domainClass, entityManager);

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.domainClass = domainClass;
    }

    public List<T> someCustomMethod(Long orgId) {

        return super.findAll();
    }
}
```

The intermediate interface

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

  List<T> someCustomMethod(Long orgId);
}
```

Custom Factory bean

```
public class GenericRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
  extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

  static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.class);

  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {

    logger.debug("#### GenericRepositoryFactoryBean : createRepositoryFactory #################");
    return new GenericRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  }

  protected static class GenericRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
      super(entityManager);
      logger.debug("#### GenericRepositoryFactory : createRepositoryFactory #################");
      this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      logger.debug("#### GenericRepositoryFactory : getTargetRepository #################");
       logger.debug("#### GenericRepositoryFactory : getTargetRepository metadata.domainType - %1 entityManager - %2",metadata.getDomainType(),entityManager);
      return new GenericRepositoryImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(), entityManager);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      logger.debug("#### GenericRepositoryFactory : getRepositoryBaseClass #################");
      // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the JpaRepositoryFactory
      // to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
      return GenericRepositoryImpl.class;
    }
  }
}
```

Spring configuration

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mynamespace.domain.repository" 
  factory-class="com.mynamespace.domain.factory.GenericRepositoryFactoryBean"/> 

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Mypu" />
  <property name="dataSource" >
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSoruce" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDS" />
  </property>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mynamespace.domain.model" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
          <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
          <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
          <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
      </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<!--TransactionManager-->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Additional info: I'm using Spring MVC, I have a config file for Spring MVC and another files for data and this is my Spring MVC file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring/*.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mynamespace.controllers"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/font/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/font/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Is not working :( any help?

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to indicate that you refer to the `GenericRepositoryImpl` from an injection point somewhere in your application classes. The samples unfortunately don't show where from exactly. Adding more of the original stack trace might help to identify the root cause of the problem. It's definitely an application component trying to autowire the implementation class directly.

Make sure you still you let your application repositories extend `GenericRepository` and only inject those into your services, controllers, etc.

EDIT: The comment thread below resulted from a misunderstanding regarding the provided sample code.

Comment: comments like this only make one loose time. Next time keep it to yourself and respect others time. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, there is a spring-data file with the exact detail expressed in the "doc", you have to download the source example provided to notice it. Bye.

Comment: Questions like yours are impossible to answer. Please take time to read the documentation, follow the steps and ask for help if fail with that or somethings hard to understand. Arbitrarily throwing code snippets together and saying: "doesn't work" is not a question at all. I didn't say: "you do it wrong, you're stupid". I said: the code you show is not even close to work, because you even seem to lack basic understanding of how Spring Data works, if that's all the code you have.

Comment: @spartancoder - Actually, sorry… I didn't notice the scrollbar in the first code window, so I thought the `GenericRepository` interface was all you had :(. It's really helpful to check the rendering when you post and make sure you mix up Spring config with code. Seeing the config below, for example, made me assume you don't have any other config except this one. I'll check your stuff and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your response. if you could take a look and help me i would really appreciate it. I didn't wanted to sounds thought, apologize too.

Comment: i will review and try to identify what other component might be trying to inizialize the reposity class. I will let you know my findings.

Comment: couldn't find any other bean or reference in the application that maybe pointing to `GenericRepositoryImpl`. I moved forward w/o using spring-jpa, this weekend i will try to provide more information about the stack trace.